# Optimally pop all the bubbles

Tags: code-golf, array, grid

In a given 2d grid of positive integers (representing different types of  "bubbles"), there are one of two actions that you can do each "step". You can either:

1. Pop an island (a connected group of bubbles - two bubbles that are diagonally adjacent are not considered connected) of the same type of bubbles, given that the island consists of **at least 2 bubbles** AND at least one bubble in said island has **no bubbles above it**.

Or,

2. Drop a **single** bubble of any type into any column, given that the chosen column is **not filled** to the top of the grid.

After one of these two steps, all bubbles will **fall** towards the bottom of the grid, and the next step will start.

The grid can also include `0`'s, which represent empty space.

## Task

Your task is: Given a \$m\times n\$ 2d grid of positive integers representing a grid of bubbles and the optional \$m\$ and \$n\$ and input, determine the fewest amount of moves in which the entire grid can be cleared of bubbles. The input grid is guaranteed to be clearable.

## Worked example

```
22222
21212
22222
21212
22222
```

The first step will be to first pop the island of `2`'s. After all the bubbles have fallen, the grid will then look like this, where the `0`'s represent empty space:

```
00000
00000
00000
01010
01010
```

The second step will be to drop a `1` bubble in the middle column, so that the grid now looks like this:

```
00000
00000
00000
01010
01110
```

And the final step is to pop the island of `1`'s, clearing the entire grid.

## Test Cases

```
m, n
grid
-> output

5, 5
22222
21212
22222
21212
22222
-> 3

7, 7
1111111
2222222
1111111
2222222
1111111
2222222
1111111
-> 7

7, 6
000000
121212
212121
121212
212121
121212
212121
-> 22

2, 7
0000000
1000001
-> 4

8, 1
0
1
2
2
2
2
2
1
-> 5

8, 2
00
10
20
20
20
20
20
10
-> 4
```

If any of y'all need it, I also made a (pretty bad) tool that will take in a list of steps (more info in the TIO link) and output the board state after those steps have been taken: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##rVbfb9s2EH7nX3F1HmytsmE7aTZ484AiQYa9DH4othWuUCgyFTORSY6iYxvD/vbs7ijJsuMVGRIFdan7@X13J5J255dGn/9g3dNTt9sVn5YSlLZrD7lxq9SDKidiFYMWd04tROmlLaFntASjQabZEgqlZSTG4F2qcH0HWm5IVgrRf90jGE1ImToJTlonS6m9XEBaIsCiMBuEJ37NYWfWsEm1B29g4YyFFG7Xt7eFBOSQQiadT5WGzBTrlY5BedioooBbie7XkCE/sVlKTJIhY/CYN5hCb9hXeiG3mDN3ZsWqQuY@ikGkegG6tvc7i0XJ67R@ycXDDFQTgmTlYvAMqyWoFKOgYI17GWCXVmYqVxmCMW6hdOrlEfYZOMhq7K7G4swmBgp4xGbw2p4I8ZvxFTkKa525c@kKFkaWuushW8rsgUYHh@gxLdQitO/HwJlQL9NHScSDJQdCnStlkQsaQCG4zNY6hRVSK2ucr96EOIO8MAY7QZEysyBedgc2LX3dnzspH0pGwCshFjLHIvxOYHpl5qTE9tNAx7CNYRcjBfl4FdPUXkUTAfioHLY/DQFDbH@ewuoLC/FBwS7IdyjXuGhUIfB8m8x3ybtpiNn2a@unU042qdU4137tNNykRSlFS/DJrfEd/87ghmjfEOt8rTOvjGZeeS1umDVB6WloHkhPcv5rLdcSpjBPgi3/nsFHnFocI261KRUlpiEtfeo8znVlZdVWFiQPk4Y90/iV7uMOUg7Tm1PFk0jU0a9MgbXh4Bxho/ySXxEYTaxx4ri4EIrXhPhjqfhjkxUDHHdtPMiV9TtQAzkgXWW7WZqihY9Gkb5NLkYr3VkdhEU4VwyLsraMNpyXc@4bua/zGVzLAIig4WBiOo3z2hhka@dmTHpa1Qh3gl50IhTW/U80ahzmw6St@3ygGyUnwVzxx6ZCg9LFfZrV/Wk1MGyy/NU2KvVf387BRDUw38MoZlAnDBrDZ7P3HHF7PJrqH2kRWthhaJ@Tmot4YFKNTQ0sodXn/QC1nsMhPWSSnOrJy8tSl6b/msK0mPRrHi@i0X8bEhQqBAp1eR2FQIBb8iIS@8xv1IsQsP9GRPr/i0afSPCFCgdxldoenmsxX7h60aC0hfK9TgydKOL7VtiQ@TjFAxVcqu9kb0WIWPse1fPvKu8kEdX1bApDEfannp1MKzU5BTV6jQRYNLNVRiwrVtHizgJ4OHWvu0R5iwYIrmfnoe56vSKX@Zi2mGNIVMzwL5QLwxHCuUpw2@agw26oY1tMMVl462T6IEAWbRizkzB2zfuY3/dHIEU@PNo5Fx8bMQFAc@zT131hj2loBl9d/NCiQKBsU5AN@yFAlr5jSlSKJiR3A4Xs8XUftZCasUXQB1qH@FGU4EiHdVL1kwLU4ahG98lzhEF03x6HRPD1qNf5xfGFC2@Jk04kwqUppK4s8s4X/XFl1nga8SmO4zCBv/n/fzrR09P3MVyKIT9iNKY/wb@jb75dwxgnagZDGPN6jOsRr0dQa6/hnG1GOJvXlXbMv@f8e1F5fTjhRVryvYDzb/ien/SdwQe4aGxoPYNLthyy5BLxiH8B)

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes for each language wins!

Comment: Does "connected" means 4 edges connected? Or 8 direction connected?

Comment: @tsh Looks like 4-connected from the linked code.

Comment: The second example can be solved in 4 moves right? Not 7

Comment: @mousetail The way I read it is that "at least one bubble in said island has no bubbles above it." means that you cannot take away a row in the middle and can only work from top to bottom therefore 7 is correct. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @mousetail ElPedro is correct, you have to pop all the layers from top to bottom.

Comment: @tsh yes, no diagonal direction, only up, down, left, right.

Answer (score 5):

## Python3, 901 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
def B(b):
 P,R,s=[(x,y)for x,j in E(b)for y,k in E(j)if k],[],[];p=P
 while p:
  x,y=p[0];q=[(x,y)];s+=p[0],
  while(o:=[X for x,y in q for X in[(x+1,y),(x,y+1),(x-1,y),(x,y-1)]if X in P and b[x][y]==b[X[0]][X[1]]and(X in s)^1]):q+=o;s+=o
  R+={*q},;p=[i for i in p if(i in s)^1]
 return R
F=lambda b:[*map(list,zip(*[[0]*i.count(0)+[j for j in i if j]for i in zip(*b)]))] 
def f(b):
 q,S=[(b,0)],{}
 while q:
  b,c=q.pop(0)
  if sum(sum(b,[]))<1:return c
  I=B(b)
  for i in I:
   if len(i)>1and sum(all(b[x-t][y]==b[x][y]or 1>b[x-t][y]for t in range(x+1))for x,y in i):
    W=eval(str(b))
    for x,y in i:W[x][y]=0
    if(str(w:=F(W))in S)^1or-~c<S[str(w)]:q+=(w,c+1),;S[str(w)]=c+1
  for y,C in E(zip(*b)):
   if C[0]<1:
    for v in{j for k in b for j in k if j}:
     W=eval(str(b));W[0][y]=v
     if(len(B(e:=F(W)))<=len(I))&((str(e)in S)^1or-~c<S[str(e)]):q+=(e,c+1),;S[str(e)]=c+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJtT9swEP68/AqLScNuXdSUF00p5gMIpH6ZEEwqUuZNSesMlzSvLpAh9te7OzukMKppSdrkXp7nzs9d0ZjbPNv/XFTr9blQ2Wqpqsgob64SckpjFnjkkl/xWoT0kTcsySvyyBdEZ@Qcomg2/M6ZC6YTcid5iM@4EJceebjVqSIFkACqEUU4lOOypZLjum89HKI2keaBCG@Iq9EgaWmNG/gETN8HFEds38f3oLMHPpNQG/PIJYmyOYnDRxk2Uog4vIESEv59KSFCbVLNvvuSBWVf5NhFDh1c9cVTr3zm0HiobVmNmQXRCdUdxiOVMqsqI1fehUijZTyPSByEvWVU0FTXhv/SBe2FULKn92b5KjN0yPrhwhJa2YArIQvZFbCAmEnGJLGqJ071kl@DUDEfMsmfnl@kLFHKmM9EuVfkBXCDCXz1aknxF4PyjB37QdvlDMITgXOEj67kBEkQlqqManbio2IIj9KUgnID86KdFRFg/knnRhaDLFWU/VQ4FcZeTUwzS06mQt1HKa1NBcWZdb3OCqbtgIY2BBpj5kMgLuiUMci4BrXzavB7dnwd2hCTOC76wGc4/XHnFWC3h2v4mdvEVlP2cs4zmAeI0nVxD2lPbiZ2d@PNeO7seJ5d7l@nGE@BB5u@d1HoGhU8partmx0LdEwY@0QtSG07imJu9ah6cxblzrLGHTD5jziPqrldhQ/tMEO3ZjozXLPNAiU6NaqiX/JMcRLv1UWqDd39lu3CRnle7BNBdnZ2vBFe3siH@/03JsQjAS/fXc4NSf9pW4J9JBjay/Nbdvv@l2WRBxskQO3LBQ5twIN63e0CRw4Byd7o7eMPMcErKhCKJnQjJSwq2@Ieofvje/8@@MlXVRsyi2pFjF6qmuQrs4XiYDvz4Xb3EbjXfwA)

Comment: [901 bytes](https://bit.ly/3cCov5E)

Comment: @Steffan Thanks, updated.